# ¿Cómo podría imprimir los datos en un solo vector y en el orden digitado? C++

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Tengo el siguiente código en C++ y estoy intentando que los valores se agrupen y se impriman en un solo vector en el mismo orden que fueron digitados.

Intenté creando un vector y haciendo un bucle `for` para que los agregue uno tras otro, pero el código se corrompe

¿Alguna sugerencia o idea?

````
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMS 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cont = 0;
    int num[MAX_ELEMS];

    printf("Ingrese hasta %i valores enteros. Un valor negativo finaliza el arreglo.\n", MAX_ELEMS);
    
    while (cont < MAX_ELEMS)
    {
        printf("\tIngrese un valor: ");
        scanf("%i", &num[cont]);

        if (num[cont] < 0)
            break;
        cont++;
    }
cout<<"Limite de numeros ingresados...\n"<<endl;    
printf("\nHa ingresado %d valores:\n", cont);
    
        while (cont-- > 0)
    {
        cout<<"El vector generado es: [";
        cout<<num[cont]<<"]"<<endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Si los pides iterando desde `0` hasta `MAX_ELEMS` ... ¿¿ Porqué al mostrarlos iteras **del revés**, desde `cont` hasta `0` ??

Comment: @Trauma He intentado hacer este ejercicio con un compañero de clases, pero no me ha quedado bien claro como mostrarlo como lo pido al usuario; he intentado cambiar el iterador y el orden de muestra sin suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que recorrer el vector en el mismo orden en el que lo haces para solicitar los datos:

```
cout << "El vector generado es: [ ";
for( int index = 0; index < cont; ++index ) {
    if( index ) {
        cout << ", ";
    }

    cout << num[index];        
}
cout << " ]\n";
```

<sub>**Nota**: Es subjetivo, pero, cuando se conocen los límites de la iteración, prefiero usar un `for( )`</sub>

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ya con esto tengo el orden garantizado, aunque solo muestra el rango desde 0 hasta 9 y los va iterando hasta 0 vector por vector; pero definitavamente se agradece enormemente tu ayuda.